# setup spring batch admin console UI with springboot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-batch-admin

I am working on migrating existing spring application to spring boot.
application has spring batch jobs. I would want to know the configuration to setup spring batch console UI with spring boot.

Existing batch jobs are configured in xml which we want to keep as it is.

spring batch admin version : 1.2.2.RELEASE
spring boot version : 1.5.10.RELEASE

just an addition so the application basically use jersey for rest services and the same application has spring batch jobs. so my intend is to keep everything together. any Idea is welcome to keep everything together and migrate to spring cloud data flow to have spring batch job monitoring.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the current application (with xml, jersey, and REST) works as-is standalone *(via `java -jar ...`)* on Spring Boot 1.5.10, it should work without any issues in Spring Cloud Data Flow, too.

You'd basically repackage the batch-job as Spring Cloud Task application. Here are a few [batch-job samples](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-task/tree/master/spring-cloud-task-samples) with `@EnableTask` annotation. There's also an end-to-end [sample](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-samples/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_batch_file_ingest) in SCDF.

Also, if you haven't already, please have a look at Spring Batch Admin to SCDF [migration guide](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/blob/master/MIGRATION.md#migrating-from-spring-batch-admin-to-spring-cloud-data-flow).

Comment: let me try doing that.
we have moved to spring boot 2.0.2. and not able to setup admin ui for version 2.0.2.

Comment: can you please help me find out how we can enhance logs to add hung thread detection and cpu starvation alerts(similar to what is supported in WAS swervers) in spring boot embedded tomcat application logs, I have asked this question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50947910/server-level-logs-in-springboot