# server level logs in springboot

Tags: spring-boot, logging, embedded-tomcat-8

I am trying to implement a single log to include information like cpu tsravation, blocked threads etc. apart from application logging.
Background :- we have migrated application to spring boot(version 2.0.1) from WebSphere server.In websphere server cpu starvation used to get logged which is not happening with springboot's logback.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please share what you have tried.

Comment: I couldn't find any configuration yet which helps in logging such info.